# Facing issue with kura and block reactive

Tags: eclipse, kura

I am implementing simple `block reactive`, and want deploy a package in `kura`.

However, every time I am upload the `.dp` file, `kura` stops working, or the file is not installed. I followed all the steps to configure eclipse and kura, including importing the zip for block reactive, and installing `mtoolkit`.

I did all necessary network setup in `kura`, too.

This is the output from `/var/log/kura-console.log`:

```
!MESSAGE Bundle 'com.bitreactive.blocks.osgi.runtime/2.6.1 already present in other deployment packages!

!ENTRY 1 0 2017-11-16 03:43:10.582 !MESSAGE [IAgent][DeploymentEventListener@49dc62] [handleComplete] Deployment package event is not successful

!ENTRY org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin 4 0 2017-11-16 03:48:25.393 !MESSAGE Bundle 'com.bitreactive.blocks.osgi.runtime/2.6.1 already present in other deployment packages!

!ENTRY 1 0 2017-11-16 03:48:25.402 !MESSAGE [IAgent][DeploymentEventListener@49dc62] [handleComplete] Deployment package event is not successful

THIS IS THE OUTPUT OF 'ss' command
    id  State       Bundle
    0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521 Fragments=74
    1   ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.coap_1.5.0
    2   INSTALLED   jdk.dio_1.0.5
    3   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.clock_1.0.1
    4   ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.buffering_3.11.2
    5   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.camel.xml_1.0.0
    6   ACTIVE      com.google.protobuf_2.6.0
    7   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.net_1.0.10
    8   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.publisher_1.0.0
    9   ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.polling_1.1.2
    10  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.quickstart_1.1.0
    11  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
    12  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.2.300.v20120522-1822
    13  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.geofence_1.5.0
    14  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.dependencymanager_3.0.0
    15  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm_1.2.3
    16  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.rpi.peripherals_1.15.0
    17  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_8.1.3.v20120522
    18  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.8.0.v201108120515
    19  ACTIVE      californium-osgi_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
    20  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.osgi.service_1.0.0
    21  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator_1.0.8
    22  ACTIVE      com.google.gson_2.2.4
    23  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-kura_2.17.2
    24  ACTIVE      org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.0
    25  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.keyteq.sms_1.1.0
    26  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.chirp_2.0.0
    27  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent_1.0.7
    28  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841
    29  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_8.1.3.v20120522
    30  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522
    31  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.3.v20120522
    32  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration_1.0.9
    33  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.properties_1.2.0
    34  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-core_2.17.2
                    Fragments=54
    35  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049
    36  ACTIVE      br.lib.camera_1.18.0
    37  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.web_2.0.3
    38  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.io_2.4.0
    39  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.8.0.v201110170705
    40  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.io_1.0.400.v20120522-2049
    41  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.status_1.0.2
    42  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.email_1.9.0
    43  ACTIVE      demo2_1.0.0
    44  ACTIVE      org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900
    45  ACTIVE      agrinode_1.0.0
    46  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.twilio.sms_1.5.0
    47  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.comm_1.0.3
    48  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.simplehttp_1.17.0
    49  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.blocks.osgi.runtime_2.6.1
    50  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20120522-1841
    51  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.3.v20120522
    52  ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
    53  ACTIVE      com.gwt.user_1.0.0
    54  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.kura.camel.sun.misc_1.0.0
                    Master=34
    55  ACTIVE      no.ntnu.item.arctis.library.sessions_1.8.1
    56  ACTIVE      br.lib.intel.edison.peripheral_1.0.2
    57  ACTIVE      joda-time_2.0.0
    58  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.300.v20120522-1841
    59  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.osgi_1.7.0
    60  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-core-osgi_2.17.2
    61  ACTIVE      slf4j.api_1.7.21
                    Fragments=104, 117
    62  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.libraries.types.coap_1.6.0
    63  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.api_1.1.0
    64  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.cm_1.0.400.v20120522-1841
    65  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.8.0.v201108120515
    66  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522
    67  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841
    68  ACTIVE      bcprov_1.53.0
    69  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.rpi.gpio_1.10.0
    70  ACTIVE      br.lib.intel.edison_1.0.1
    71  ACTIVE      br.lib.rpi_1.9.0
    72  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.kml_1.2.0
    73  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.ble.tisensortag_1.0.3
    74  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.kura.sun.misc_1.0.0
                    Master=0
    75  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.publisher_1.0.2
    76  ACTIVE      com.codeminders.hidapi_1.1.2
    77  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.certificates_1.0.3
    78  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.position_1.0.2
    79  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.exec_1.3.0
    80  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.200.v20120522-1841
    81  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.timers_1.6.1
    82  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-stream_2.17.2
    83  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.sms.clickatell_1.7.0
    84  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.aggregation_1.1.0
    85  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.200.v20120522-2049
    86  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.camel_1.1.0
    87  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.watchdog_1.0.1
    88  ACTIVE      no.ntnu.item.arctis.library.speech_2.8.0
    89  ACTIVE      org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.rpc_3.0.0.20110411-0918
    90  ACTIVE      org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000
    91  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522
    92  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.features.mqtt_1.2.0
    93  RESOLVED    log4j.apache-log4j-extras_1.1.0
                    Master=126
    94  ACTIVE      org.blocksreactive.kura.demo_1.0.0
    95  ACTIVE      org.knowhowlab.osgi.monitoradmin_1.0.2
    96  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.gson_1.6.0
    97  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater_1.0.2
    98  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core_1.0.10
    99  ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.iterator_1.5.0
    100 ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.subsystem.mqtt_1.2.0
    101 ACTIVE      jcl.over.slf4j_1.7.21
    102 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.crypto_1.0.5
    103 ACTIVE      org.usb4java_1.0.0
    104 RESOLVED    slf4j.log4j12_1.7.21
                    Master=61
    105 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin_0.9.5
    106 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3_1.0.1
    107 ACTIVE      osgi.cmpn_4.3.0.201111022214
    108 ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.2.2.v20111214-1400
    109 ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.counter_1.9.0
    110 ACTIVE      demo1_1.0.0
    111 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud_1.0.9
    112 ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.flowlogic_1.13.0
    113 ACTIVE      bcpkix_1.53.0
    114 ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.kura_1.1.0
    115 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120521-2346
    116 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory_1.0.0
    117 RESOLVED    slf4j.jdk14_1.7.21
                    Master=61
    118 ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.net_3.1.0.v201205071737
    119 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813
    120 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net_1.0.2
    121 ACTIVE      pi4j-core_1.0.0
    122 ACTIVE      rb.kura.demo_2.2.2_2.1.1
    123 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.0.v20120522-1841
    124 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3_1.0.2
    125 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.gpio_1.0.2
    126 ACTIVE      log4j_1.2.17 Fragments=93
    127 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841
    128 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.example.beacon_1.0.2
    129 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.300.v20120622-204750
    130 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822
    131 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.usb_1.0.2
    132 ACTIVE      br.lib.rpi.berryclip_1.9.0
    133 ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.periodictimers_1.5.0
    134 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.metatype_1.2.0.v20120522-1841
    135 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.0.v20120522-1841
    136 ACTIVE      com.bitreactive.library.mqtt_2.12.8
    137 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.bluetooth_1.0.7
    138 ACTIVE      usb4java-javax_1.0.0
    139 ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.lang3_3.4.0
    140 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.200.v20120523-2004
```

This is the output of the `ls` command:

```
    ID  State           Component Name          Located in bundle
        1   Active      org.eclipse.kura.clock.ClockService         org.eclipse.kura.emulator.clock(bid=3)
        2   Active      org.eclipse.kura.camel.xml.XmlRouterComponent           org.eclipse.kura.camel.xml(bid=5)
        3   Active      org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.publisher.ExamplePublisher           org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.publisher(bid=8)
        4   Active      org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.quickstart.GatewayRouterJava         org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.quickstart(bid=10)
        5   Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.quickstart.GatewayRouterXml          org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.quickstart(bid=10)
        6   Active      org.eclipse.kura.emulator.Emulator          org.eclipse.kura.emulator(bid=21)
        7   Active      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent           org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent(bid=27)
        8   Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration.CloudConfigurationHandler           org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration(bid=32)
        9   Active      org.eclipse.kura.configuration.ConfigurationService         org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration(bid=32)
        10  Active      org.eclipse.equinox.event           org.eclipse.equinox.event(bid=35)
        11  Active      org.eclipse.kura.web.Console            org.eclipse.kura.web(bid=37)
        12  Active      org.eclipse.kura.status.CloudConnectionStatusService            org.eclipse.kura.core.status(bid=41)
        13  Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.comm.CommConnectionFactory            org.eclipse.kura.core.comm(bid=47)
        14  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.example.ble.tisensortag.BluetoothLe            org.eclipse.kura.example.ble.tisensortag(bid=73)
        15  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.example.publisher.ExamplePublisher         org.eclipse.kura.example.publisher(bid=75)
        16  Active      org.eclipse.kura.certificate.CertificatesService            org.eclipse.kura.core.certificates(bid=77)
        17  Active      org.eclipse.kura.position.PositionService           org.eclipse.kura.emulator.position(bid=78)
        18  Active      org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.aggregation.GatewayRouter            org.eclipse.kura.example.camel.aggregation(bid=84)
        19  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.camel.KuraCloudComponentResolver           org.eclipse.kura.camel(bid=86)
        20  Active      org.eclipse.kura.watchdog.WatchdogService           org.eclipse.kura.emulator.watchdog(bid=87)
        21  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater.Heater         org.eclipse.kura.demo.heater(bid=97)
        22  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.data.DataService           org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=98)
        23  Active      org.eclipse.kura.db.DbService           org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=98)
        24  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.core.data.transport.mqtt.MqttDataTransport         org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=98)
        25  Active      org.eclipse.kura.ssl.SslManagerService          org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=98)
        26  Active      org.eclipse.kura.system.SystemService           org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=98)
        27  Active      org.eclipse.kura.system.SystemAdminService          org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=98)
        28  Active      org.eclipse.kura.crypto.CryptoService           org.eclipse.kura.core.crypto(bid=102)
        29  Unsatisfied     demo1.demo1.Component           demo1(bid=110)
        30  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.cloud.CloudService         org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=111)
        31  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.cloud.CloudCallService         org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=111)
        32  Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.factory.DefaultCloudServiceFactory          org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=111)
        33  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.cloud.app.command.CommandCloudApp          org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=111)
        34  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory.CamelFactory           org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory(bid=116)
        35  Active      org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory.CamelCloudServiceFactory           org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory(bid=116)
        36  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService         org.eclipse.kura.emulator.net(bid=120)
        37  Active      org.eclipse.kura.gpio.GPIOService           org.eclipse.kura.emulator.gpio(bid=125)
        38  Active      org.eclipse.kura.example.beacon.BeaconExample           org.eclipse.kura.example.beacon(bid=128)
        39  Active      org.eclipse.kura.usb.UsbService         org.eclipse.kura.emulator.usb(bid=131)
        40  Active      org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothService         org.eclipse.kura.l
```

Output of `/var/log/kura.log`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F042L.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response, I just noticed this post. Have you resolved  your issue? I see a couple of things wrong. The first, your demo component is not active (it is Unsatisfied). Can you issue the OSGi command comp 29 to see what is wrong with the component? The second, it looks like mToolkit is trying to install a second copy of the deployment package. You may have to uninstall your DP first, then re-install. It may be easier to use the Kura web UI for managing the DP instead of mToolkit.

Comment: No, I am facing same issue as before. I am using Kura web UI from starting also I already uninstalls and installed DP without using mtoolkit. I will check comp 29 command and let you know

Comment: I am also trying to use eclipse iot greenhouse example , but after deploying on kura its remain inactive . please provide configuration steps because I did not change code so there may be some configuration missing. I directly imported greenhouse project in eclipse and generate .dp file of org.eclipse.iot.greenhouse.publisher and deployed on kura but it does not comes in service section , in the code everything looks perfect still getting issue.I want to develop different project but with the same steps. So please help with the configuration details.